# Перестают работать коды JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем добрый день.

Может, кто-нибудь поделится информацией. В последнее время активно перестают работать JS скрипты, написанные в старом формате старыми методами на чистом JS. Кто-нибудь знает, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @alexsis20102, может быть, jquery обновили?

Comment: Нет именно JS, не jquery, раньше работали, теперь по какой-то причине работать перестают.

Comment: Может быть, использовали [устаревшие](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features) возможности? По мере обновления браузеров могли отвалиться, например, [`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear).

А вообще в консоль заглядывали? – там могут быть подробные сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: Да я тоже думаю, что это все из-за обновления браузеров. А подобные моменты могу происходить из-за обновления сервера? Знаю, что JS  не серверный язык, но все же.

Comment: Могут и из-за обновления сервера: напр., если JS код генерится налету, и из-за обновлений вдруг начинает выдавать среди JS кода серверное сообщение об ошибке. Посмотрите исходный код страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Благодарю всех за очень полезную информацию. Подытожим. Есть ряд причин, из-за которых может перестать работать JS:

1. Из-за обновлений браузера отпали какие-либо функции.
2. Из-за автоматических генераций скриптов и ошибки сервера при их генерации.
3. Из-за перенастройки сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Функции чистого javascript-а работает не во всех браузерах.
Лучше использовать jQuery, он полностью кроссбраузерный.

Comment: да, конечно. в w3m и linx jQuery также работает:) А ещё не все версии jQuery работают во всех браузерах. К примеру последние версии почти не работают в древних (относительно) эксплорерах.

Comment: О Jquery речь вообще не идет. Тут проблема с чистым JS. Просто пытаюсь выяснить возможные причины отказа от работы скриптов. Сейчас просто перевожу старые скрипты на Jquery все работает. Но ситуация неприятная.

Comment: смотрите в лог. (F12  в большинстве современных броузеров, потом вкладка console). Там могут быть ответы на Ваши вопросы.

Мои предложения:

 - к скриптам нет доступа (к примеру, кто то поднастроил апач)
 - скриты немного переименовали. Визуально урлы выглядят валидными, а по факту - нет. error_log апача в помощь.